# Simple c array calculator drops the first number

Tags: c, arrays

This is part of my assignment. I have to make a calculator using arrays.
this is the addition part of it.

It works fine but the problem is, it drops the first digit. array size is for example 10 . it doesn't show the first digit whenever addition has remainder.

for example i want to add 5 9 7 5 3 1 0 0 0 0 with 5 0 8 6 4 2 0 0 0 0. the true answer is 11061730000 but this program shows 1061730000 (drops first 1).

how do i fix this behavior??

code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE_MAX 10
#define SIZE_USE SIZE_MAX-1

int main()
{
    int i;

    int inum_firstPTR[SIZE_MAX] = {5, 9, 7, 5, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    int inum_secondPTR[SIZE_MAX] = {5, 0, 8, 6, 4, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0};

    int add_resultPTR[SIZE_MAX] = {0}; //initializing result array

    for (i = SIZE_USE; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (add_resultPTR[i] = inum_firstPTR[i] + inum_secondPTR[i] < 10)
        {
            add_resultPTR[i] = inum_firstPTR[i] + inum_secondPTR[i];
        }
        else
        {
            add_resultPTR[i] = inum_firstPTR[i] + inum_secondPTR[i] - 10;
            inum_firstPTR[i - 1] = inum_firstPTR[i - 1] + 1;
        }
    }

    puts("");

    for (i = 0; i < SIZE_MAX; i++)
    {
        printf("%d", add_resultPTR[i]);
    }

    puts("");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The answer does not fir the available space: you have overflow. Either make more space available or say something like the C standard: *overflow invokes Undefined Behaviour* and live happily ever after

Comment: Use parenthesis in your macros!! `#define SIZE_USE (SIZE_MAX-1)` Otherwise something like `2 * SIZE_USE` will give very bad results (`10 * SIZE_MAX-1` is equivalent to `(10 * SIZE_MAX) - 1`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (i = SIZE_USE; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (add_resultPTR[i] = inum_firstPTR[i] + inum_secondPTR[i] < 10)
    {
        add_resultPTR[i] = inum_firstPTR[i] + inum_secondPTR[i];
    }
    else //carry
    {
        if ( i > 0) // normal carry to next element
        {
            add_resultPTR[i] = inum_firstPTR[i] + inum_secondPTR[i] - 10;
            inum_firstPTR[i - 1] = inum_firstPTR[i - 1] + 1;
        }
        else // element [0], no more elements to carry to
        {
            add_resultPTR[i] = inum_firstPTR[i] + inum_secondPTR[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

addition of 5+5+carry1 is 11 but `add_resultPTR[0]` can only store 1 and there is no position before `[0]` to store carry1 therefore it only prints from 1.
moreover, 11061730000 are 11 digits how do you suppose to fit into an array of SIZE_MAX 10.
define `SIZE_MAX` as 11 and then to prevent from overflow store addition of `inum_firstPTR[SIZE_MAX]` and `inum_firstPTR[SIZE_MAX]` from `add_resultPTR[0]` to `add_resultPTR[10]` and print it in reverse i.e. if `add_resultPTR[10]` is 1 then from `[10]` to `[0]` otherwise from `[9]` to `[0]`.